# Prevent superposition of titles in header (fancy)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to prevent the issue of having titles superposed in the header of my report.

I am using the following code:

```
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
```

Actually, when the current subsection is too long and the section as well, both titles are superposed in the middle of the header. Is there a way to prevent it? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Typical example :

```
  \section{This is a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious title for a section}
  \newpage
  \subsection{I am also a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious subtitle}
```

When you check the header of the second page, section and subsection displayed are superposed. I wish I could have at least the entire text of the section and on the left part the start of the subsection with "..." before it becomes superposed.

ie, I wish I could have this kind of header :

```
  1.1 I am also a ...       1 THIS IS A SUPERCALIFRAGILISTICEXPIDALIDOCIOUS TITLE FOR A SECTION
```

**EDIT 2**

As requested, a minimum working example. It concerns the second page header.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
\section{This is a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious title for a section}
\newpage
  \subsection{I am also a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious subtitle}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Header12: you don't have to post your exact code, but a minimal working example, that is a document starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}` which reproduces the problem. Furthermore, you just have to load the relevant packages able to reproduce the problem, not the whole preamble. :)

Comment: You should include an MWE.
I don't know if it is possible to do that automatically, but what you could do is, you could use the following syntax of the \section / \subsection commands:
\section[short title for headers]{long title}
however, this also affects the TOC

Comment: It's necessary at leastu to know the `fancyhdr` settings you're using and the document class. Note that having both the section and subsection titles in a single header makes it easy to get superpositions, because the space is limited.

Comment: Unfortunately the proposed solution is not working on the MWE I provided. Thank you in advance for any help you would proposed. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94901/17151) and manually decide, case-by-case, what to show on the header. 
I think it's quite impossible do this automatically.
As an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%any chances to remove this?
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{
    \section[#2]{#2%
    \sectionmark{#1}}\sectionmark{#1}}

\newcommand{\markedsubsection}[2]{
    \subsection[#2]{#2%
    \subsectionmark{#1}} \subsectionmark{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% \markedsection{HEADER}{PAGE AND TOC}
\markedsection{This is a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious title\dots}{This is a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious title for a section}
\lipsum

\markedsubsection{I am also a super\dots}{I am also a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious subtitle}
\lipsum[3]
\markedsubsection{Another veeery\dots}{Another very very very very very very long title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section[section toc]{section normal text}
\sectionmark{section header}

\subsection[subsec toc]{subsec normal text}
\subsectionmark{subsection header}

lorem ipsum
\newpage
lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

it might not be as simple as I thought. Apparently your \usepackage[francais]{babel} gives some problem. I extended your code here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
\section{This is a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious title for a section}
\newpage
\subsection{I am also a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious subtitle%
%\subsectionmark{code1}%
}
\subsectionmark{code}

\newpage
lorem ipsum


\end{document}
```

you can see, the problem is that at the first page of the subsection, there is still the long header of the subsection. If you know uncomment the line with `code1` everything looks like you want it. However, I uncommented the babel command as well, since I got an error message because of that and I don't know yet, how this can be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, isn't there a command for treating this kind of issue automatically? Everytime I am using this kind of hand-made solutions, I find out that there is something already existing in latex.

Comment: The problem is, how shall the compiler decide, where to abbreviate? Therefore, it only gives you a warning and you can then decide, what to do against it.

Comment: Hello, Your solution is still not working. Could you please help me? Regards.