# Alternate section title in header, also when new section starts at top of page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design

I'm using `fancyhdr` to display the current section title in the header of even-numbered pages of a `book`. I achieve this with the following code:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\scshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\scshape #1}{}}
```

Some section titles are long and I have to display a shorter title in the headers (but not in the table of contents). Usually the following works:

```
\section[Long section title]{Long section title}
\marksection{Short section title}
```

However, when an odd-numbered page starts with a new section, this results in the `long section name` on that first page. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94892/how-to-use-short-subsection-title-in-header-but-not-in-table-of-contents), the problem is solved with this method:

```
\section[Long section title]{Long section title%
\sectionmark{Short section title}}
\sectionmark{Short section title}
```

(see also the macro provided in the answer).
But this doesn't work for me either. I noticed they used the `scrartcl` document class while I'm using `book`, which may be the reason. 
Here is my MWE (hopefully sufficiently minimal):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\scshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\scshape #1}{}}

\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{\section[#2]{#2% See the linked answer
\sectionmark{#1}}
\sectionmark{#1}}

\author{Author}
\title{Test book}

\begin{document}    
\maketitle    
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Test chapter]{Test chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4-11]

% Method 1
%\sectionmark{Short section title}
%\section[Long section title]{Long section title}
%\sectionmark{Short section title}

% Method 2
\markedsection{Short section title}{Long section title}    

\lipsum[1-6]    
\end{document}
```

(I can provide a .pdf if it helps). Some answers suggest using the KOMA-script book class, but this is not an option because the book is almost finished and it's rather too late to switch classes.

Comment: `titleps` might work better here than `fancyhdr`. It is by the author of `titlesec` and is designed to play nicely with it. It has a lot more facilities for managing marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch to `titleps`, you can use your current code and it seems to work. Better would probably be to use the package's extended support for additional sets of marks, avoiding the need for a workaround.

Or, since you are using `titlesec`, you could probably just set the sectioning command up to avoid the need for special measures. However, without seeing how you are using this already, it is difficult to say for sure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{\section[#2]{#2% See the linked answer
\sectionmark{#1}}
\sectionmark{#1}}

\newpagestyle{myfancy}[\normalfont\normalsize\scshape]{%
  \setheadrule{.4pt}%
  \sethead[\toptitlemarks\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\toptitlemarks\thesection\space\sectiontitle}%
  \setfoot*{}{}{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{myfancy}

\author{Author}
\title{Test book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Test chapter]{Test chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4-11]

\markedsection{Short section title}{Long section title}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: top marks]