# Long title problem with fancyhdr and titlesec

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec

I have the same problem as [How to use short subsection title in header but not in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94892/how-to-use-short-subsection-title-in-header-but-not-in-table-of-contents), and the solution given works almost well.

The difference is that also use the package `titlesec`. Here the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{\section[#2]{#2%
\sectionmark{#1}}
\sectionmark{#1}}

\newcommand{\markedsubsection}[2]{\subsection[#2]{#2%
\subsectionmark{#1}}
\subsectionmark{#1}}

\lhead{\nouppercase \leftmark} \chead{} \rhead{\nouppercase \rightmark}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\markedsection{short section}{Some section with quite a lengthy title}

\lipsum

\markedsubsection{short subsection}{Very very very long title of subsection}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But on the page where the subsection appears for the first time, the title in the header has not been modified, it is still the original long title, whereas on the next pages, the subsection titles ih the header is the short one. I want of course the short one even the first time. If I remove the titlesec package, everything works fine, as on the other post.
Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to tackle the problem with `fancyhdr`, but since you use `titlesec`, I suggest doing it with the `titleps` module of `titlesec` instead. For unnumbered subsections, I had to define a new command (`nonumsubsection`) because `titlesec` doesn't seem to manage the formatting of starred (sub)sections with an optional argument :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Dodgson,
 author = {Lewis Carroll},
 title = {The Hunting of the Snark},
 year = {1876},
 publisher = {Macmillan},
 owner = {Bernard},
 timestamp = {2016.01.27}
}
 @book{lear72,
 author = {Edward Lear},
 year = {1872},
 title = {More Nonsense Pictures, Rhymes, Botany, Etc. },
 address = {London},
 publisher = {Robert John Bush}
 }
@book{Lear12,
author = {Edward Lear},
year = {2011},
title ={The Dong with a Luminous Nose},
address= {Petaluma (CA)},
Publisher = {Pomegranate Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox, chngcntr} 
\usepackage[pagestyles, toctitles]{titlesec}
\newcommand\nonumsubsection[2][]{{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}\def\thesubsection{\relax}\ifblank{#1}{\subsection{#2}}{\subsection[#1]{#2}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}\counterwithin{subsection}{section}}
\newpagestyle{ownstyle}{%
\headrule
\sethead{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\ifnumequal{\value{secnumdepth}}{0}{\subsectiontitle}{\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}}%
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%
\pagestyle{ownstyle}
\newpagestyle{bibetc}{%
\sethead{\scshape\sectiontitle}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\section[Short Section]{Some section with quite a lengthy title}

\lipsum

\subsection[Short subsection]{Very very very long title of subsection}

\lipsum

\nonumsubsection[Unnumbered subsection]{Very very very long title of unnumbered subsection}

\lipsum

\subsection{Another numbered subsection}
\lipsum

\pagestyle{bibetc}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly! I didn't know this package extension, can it do the same as fancyhdr does ? To be complete, if someone has a solution using fancyhdr, it might be helpfull for others.

Comment: As far as I know, it can do more or less the same, without having the hassle to cope with marks. I always could do what I wanted with titleps. Note it is mentioned in the doc of titlesec, but its own documentation with more details.

Comment: I unchecked the solution so far because I have some issues with the titeps solution, if nobody can solve the original problem, I'll check it back. The problem I have is I want some sections unnumbered, and in that case it becomes very tedious because using starred section does not go along with titleps. Moreover, for the appendix, it is the same, since apparently Latex uses `\markboth` and this is actually the problem. So the use of fancyhdr would be better for me for those reasons, but I will have again my original problem... I don't know if this is very clear

Comment: @antoine: For the starred (sub)sections, I have a solution. For appendix what you want is not quite clear to me. Could give some details on what you want?

Comment: Oups sorry, it is not the appendix but the references. When I use `\bibliography` the header is the number of the previous section followed by "References", even using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. So the number shoud not be there

Comment: I'll try to see that later, I don't have time at the moment. Do you use `biblatex` for your bibliography?

Comment: Yes no problem. I use `bibtex`

Comment: @antoine: I've updated my answer. Does it solve all your problems now?

Comment: Yes almost !! What should I change if I want an unnumbered section, not only subsection ? Otherwise it is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot !

Comment: You should first define  a `\nonumsection` with this adapted code: `\newcommand\nonumsection[2][]{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}\def\thesection{\relax}\ifblank{#1}{\section{#2}}{\section[#1]{#2}}\par
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}`. For the rest, it would be easier to have a concrete example. I suppose that if a section is unnumbered, you want its subsections to be unnumbered too?

Comment: I have many error with your last code. Actually, the only sections I want unnumbered are the introduction and conclusion, so there are no subsection in that case

Comment: Well, in this case it will be simpler. The `bibetc`  page style  is done for that (if you don't like smallcaps in header, remove it  from the code). So don't call `ownstyle` in the preamble. Instead call `bibetc` just before the introduction, the `ownstyle` after the intro and `bibetc` again just before the conclusion. This should reasonably work.

Comment: Just to be sure I use a `section*{}`, right (since I want the section unnumbered) ? I am asking because using the `bibetc` style, I don't have anything for the introduction, and in the header of the conclusion, I have just the title of the previous section

Comment: I'll have to make some tests. Just a question: do you want introduction and conclusion to appear in the table of contents? Or only in  headers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38686/discussion-between-antoine-and-bernard).